# Query doesn´t show results if some columns are empty using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys I´m trying to get results from two different tables using mysql and codeigniter, and actually I´m able to do it the problem is that one table (empleados) has data like name, last name, etc. (see the picture) and the other table (cuentas) has empty columns because I´m gonna insert them later based on the result, the problem is that if cuentas doesn´t have any data stored, it doesn´t show the results from the other table (name, last_name etc), so I want to see the results even if the other table doesn´t have stored data.

This is the controller:

```
function search2()
{
  if ($_POST) {
      $Interno=$_POST['Interno'];
  }else{
    $Interno = '';
  }
  $this->db->select('empleados.Interno, empleados.Curp, empleados.Nombre, empleados.A_Paterno, empleados.A_Materno, cuentas.Clabe, cuentas.Banco, cuentas.Observaciones, cuentas.Status');
$this->db->from('empleados');
$this->db->join('cuentas','cuentas.Interno = empleados.Interno');
$this->db->where('empleados.Interno', $Interno);
$this->db->where('cuentas.Status !=', 'I');
$q = $this->db->get();
$data = array();
$data['records'] = $q->result_array();
$this ->load -> view('main/indice', $data); 


}
```

This is the view:

```
 <?php
    foreach ($records as $row) {
            echo"<br></br>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Interno</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Interno'  name ='Interno' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='Interno' value='".$row['Interno']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>CURP</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='curp' name ='curp' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='Curp' value='".$row['Curp']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>nombre</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='nombre' name ='nombre' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='Nombre' value='".$row['Nombre']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Apellido Paterno</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='A_Paterno' name ='A_Paterno' class='form-control Input col-sm-2' placeholder='Apellido Paterno' value='".$row['A_Paterno']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Apellido Materno</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='A_Materno' name ='A_Materno' class='form-control Input col-sm-1' placeholder='Apellido Materno' value='".$row['A_Materno']."'>"; 

               echo "<label class='control-label'>Clabe</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Clabe' name ='Clabe' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='' value='".$row['Clabe']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Banco</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Banco' name ='Banco' class='form-control Input col-sm-2' placeholder='' value='".$row['Banco']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Observaciones</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Observaciones' name ='Observaciones' class='form-control Input col-sm-1' placeholder='' value='".$row['Observaciones']."'>"; 
    }
  ?>
```

This is the page when table "cuentas" doesn´t have any info but table "empleados" does.
[image]

This is the page when table "cuentas" has data 
[image]

Again I´d like to see the results of the first table even if the second one has empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join instead of inner join, Also move your `cuentas.Status` filter in join part, Doing this you will get `empleados` records if there are no associated rows found in `cuentas` table

```
$this->db->select('empleados.Interno, empleados.Curp, empleados.Nombre, empleados.A_Paterno, empleados.A_Materno, cuentas.Clabe, cuentas.Banco, cuentas.Observaciones, cuentas.Status');
$this->db->from('empleados');
$this->db->join('cuentas',"cuentas.Interno = empleados.Interno AND cuentas.Status !='I'", 'left');
$this->db->where('empleados.Interno', $Interno);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: @AdrianJimenez no worries just have a look at [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)